# private member of c++ classes

Tags: arrays, class, visual-c++, bitmap

i have a problem, about render bitmap files in opengl (manually):
how get data from unsigned char pointer in order to use them in glDrawPixels function?
(unsigned char *bitmap_Image)

```
class bitmap
{
private:
    unsigned long BPP;
    unsigned long width;
    unsigned long height;
    unsigned long size;
    unsigned char *bitmap_Image; // how use this member??
    unsigned int bps;

public:
    bitmap();
    ~bitmap();

    bool Load(const char *filename);
    #pragma pack(push,1)

     typedef struct 
     {
     WORD bfType;
     DWORD bfSize;
     DWORD bfReserved;
     DWORD bfOffBits;
     }BITMAPFILEHEADER;

     //BITMAPINFOHEADER
     typedef struct 
     {
     DWORD biSize;
     LONG biWidth;
     LONG biHeight;
     WORD biPlanes;
     WORD biBitCount;
     DWORD biCompression;
     DWORD biSizeImage;
     LONG biXPelsPerMeter;
     LONG biYPelsPerMeter;
     DWORD biClrUsed;
     DWORD biClrImportant;
     }BITMAPINFOHEADER;

     #pragma pack(pop)

     BITMAPFILEHEADER FileHeader;
     BITMAPINFOHEADER InfoHeader;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Having read the question once again, you have to declare a public member wich returns the internal pointer bitmap_Image.

```
...
public:
   const unsigned char* GetImageData() const { return bitmap_Image; }
   int GetWidth() const { return width; }
   int GetHeight() const { return heigth; }
   int GetBPP() const { return BPP; }
...
```

There's no other (standart and safe) way around the privateness of the field.

Assuming that BPP is BitsPerPixel and it is either 24 or 32, you might call

```
 bitmap* YourBmp = ... // construct and load

 const unsigned char* Ptr = YourBmp->GetImageData();
 int W = YourBmp->GetWidth();
 int H = YourBmp->GetHeight();
 int Fmt  = (YourBmp->GetBPP() == 24) ? GL_BGR : GL_BGRA; // or maybe GL_RGB or GL_RGBA
 int Type = GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE;
 glDrawPixels(W, H, Fmt, Type, Ptr);
```

There are problems if your image uses palette (8-bit or less) - you have to convert it to RGB(A). There's another problem if the size of a single line of your image is not divisible by 4, you might get invalid array in `bitmap_Image` field.

`glRasterPos` or `glWindowPos` will help you to set the position where you want to render your image.

If you are using GL2.0+ without fixed-function (though it is unlikely) then you should create the 4-vertex array and render the quad with a simple fragment shader.

Comment: I'd make this a constant function (also return pointer to constant data)

Comment: @datenwolf: At first I just wasn't sure about glDrawPixels parameter (const or non-const), now I looked up the docs and added the const modifier to GetImageData.

Comment: thank you for edit .today i use this cods and after build solution and run program got error "program has stopped working"

Comment: so i decide to print bitmap_Image array in console (cmd) and found that const unsigned char* Ptr = YourBmp->GetImageData(); cant show my bitmap data :|

Comment: "Can't show" - do you mean the program stopped working after adding the 'const' modifier or do you mean that the program just does not work ? Maybe you have an error in your constructor and load() functions. One cannot guess.

Comment: LoadBitmap(const char *Filename); i use this and its load but raster data didn't save in array "const unsigned char* Ptr = YourBmp->GetImageData();" this command not work true XD... beter change my question : how show bmp files in a simple window manually

Comment: and finall i find how display bmp files ^_^ here: http://code.google.com/p/multiproposito/source/browse/trunk/Proyecto/loadbmp.cpp?r=3&spec=svn3

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to load your bitmap binary blob into a byte (aka. `unsigned char`) array, then passing it to your `glDrawPixels()` function :

```
unsigned char[] myBitmap;
...
glDrawPixels( ..., &myBitmap, ... );
```